# Why can't I use brace enclosed initializer list to call copy constructor?

Tags: c++11

I was trying to run the code from the new C++ Programming Language book written by Bjarne Stroustrup seems like does not work. Which compiler supports the the grammar `S y {x};` in the code? Can not compile, I tried g++, vc++, not yet Clang, that error code supposes to be an initialization, after, I changed that code to `S y = x;` an assignment, but did not output the result as comments , am I wrong somewhere?

```
struct S {
     int* p;    // a pointer
};

S x {new int{0}};
void f()
{
     S y {x};              // "copy" x

     *y.p = 1;             // change y; affects x
     *x.p = 2;             // change x; affects y
     delete y.p;           // affects x and y
     y.p = new int{3};     // OK: change y; does not affect x
     *x.p = 4;             // oops: write to deallocated memory
}
```

Then I rewrote the code in C++03 version, It work as described, like this:

```
struct S
{
    int *p;  
};

int main()
{
   S x;
   x.p = new int;
   *(x.p) = 0;

   S y = x;
   *y.p = 1;
   *x.p = 2;
   delete y.p;
   y.p = NULL;
   x.p = NULL;
   y.p = new int;
   *(y.p) = 3;
   *(x.p)= 4;
}
```

Is there any magic behind, or just the code in the book is not correct. Any advise thanks.

Comment: Which version of the mentioned compiler(s) are you using? use g++ 4.7.x and above(4.8.1 is c++11 feature complete).

Comment: @Koushik, G++ 4.7.3. I was using cygwin on windows, it supports g++ up to 4.7.3

Comment: there must be something else going wrong.  Because if you're using 4.7.3 I can promise it supports that syntax.  What's your exact error message?

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity, I think, will be better to ask the OP about the **real** question. So, zyangpointer, what is your question: "Why does  the first code not compiled", or "Why does the first code not cause segfault(or something else) like the second one"?

Comment: VC++ doesn't support uniform initialization syntax (the "curly brace" initialization) g++/clang will but they need "-std=c++11" on the command line.

Comment: @soon, sorry for the inaccuracy , simply saying, the first could not be compiled in G++ 4.7.3 which I initially tried.

Comment: @Casey, right,that is why I primarily use g++ for C++11.

Comment: @zyangpointer, what is your compiler error message, exactly?  How are you compiling the program, exactly?

Comment: @zyangpointer, so, please, edit the question to remove disambiguation. You may use [this code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=35a13ee95563c8050ce4244bd3b90776-ce759ceac3a1c87b565ff35b2f7d6b5c), it describes your problem fully.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity,  the compiler error is not readable, long space with random letters.

Comment: @soon, thanks, I changed the question title as you suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known problem with the C++11 wording. The C++14 CD doesn't have this problem fixed either (see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1467 for the corresponding DR).

We can hope for compilers to implement a future fix for this in their C++11 and C++14 mode retroactively. The next issues list revision should contain proposed wording for issue 1467 that fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

After the line `delete y.p;`, the memory pointed to by `x.p` and `y.p` is deallocated. Hence `x.p` is now pointing at deallocated memory.

After the line `y.p = new int{3};`, x.p and y.p are no longer pointing at the same memory since the **pointer** `y.p` has been reassigned.

`x.p` is still pointing to the deallocated memory from the `delete` line, so when you try to dereference it you get a seg fault.

Comment: To clarify: `x.p` and `y.p` *may* points to a same memory after `y.p` has been reassigned, in case if memory was allocated in same address. [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f532588e38ca54c2a122d6172b668f73-ce759ceac3a1c87b565ff35b2f7d6b5c). It's UB, this code may or may not  cause segfault. But the answer is correct, +1.

Comment: This is not the question being asked...  The question being asked has to do with a compile error.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity, I don't think so. Quote from the question: _"... but did not output the result as comments, am I wrong somewhere?"_. Also, the title: _"... seems does not work"_, not _"...seems does not compile"_.

Comment: I might be overestimating OP, but the question actually contains the answer posted in the program comments...  Also he specifically called out a part of the code that he's not understanding/having trouble with, the brace initialized copy constructor...

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity I think it's been edited since I posted my answer, OP didn't specify what the problem was initially